# spl-token 0.2.3 not working due "missing config", but it's not missing

Tags: spl-token, solana-cli, spl-token-cli

solana fams, so I just install spl-token 0.2.3, now when I try to do simple spl-token transfer via ledger I get this:

```
error: default signer is required, please specify a valid default signer by identifying a valid configuration file using the --config-file argument, or by creating a valid config at the default location of ~/.config/solana/cli/config.yml using the solana config command
```

but my config file exist!

```
➜ ls ~/.config/solana/cli/
config.yml
```

```
solana 1.15.2
spl-token 0.2.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `solana config get` for more information about your config. It should give you the default keypair in the "Keypair Path":

```
$ solana config get
Config File: /home/you/.config/solana/cli/config.yml
RPC URL: https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com
WebSocket URL: wss://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/ (computed)
Keypair Path: /home/you/.config/solana/id.json
Commitment: confirmed
```

Otherwise, you may need to provide the full command that you're running to transfer tokens